# Was it an offer? or part of the screening process?

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, hiring

I'm having trouble determining where I stand with a company. I did a Skype interview (they're located out of state), then they asked me about my salary requirements, I told them, and they gave me a counter range and said something like "You have a lot of potential and we believe you can be trained quickly. If you're still interested, we would like to further discuss you joining our team."

Was this an official offer?? (I know nothing is "official" without a letter, but...) I suggested meeting in person and said I was available to go out there immediately - they delayed a few weeks, which concerned me... I am just not sure if I'm going in as "the" candidate or one of the finalists. If it isn't obvious when I go in there, how can I smoothly ask...

Might be worth noting that this is a very specialized field, and there were probably very few candidates to begin with...

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you actually have an interview date confirmed?

Answer (score 5):

> "If you're still interested, we would like to further discuss you
>   joining our team."
>
> Was this an official offer?

**No.**

Or more properly, it's an offer to "further discuss" things.

A real offer has at least an agreed-upon salary and benefits package, job responsibilities, reporting relationship, and a start date.

A "we would like to discuss" statement is a chance to talk more, and perhaps nail down the details. It might lead to a real offer, but it might not.

> I am just not sure if I'm going in as "the" candidate or one of the
>   finalists.

There's no real way to know for sure. If they will pay for your visit, then you should consider yourself at least a serious candidate.